# Factorial function yields incorrect values for the high parameters

Tags: c#, console, console-application, factorial

This small program tests the two approaches of computing the factorial - by iteration and by recursion.

Factorial.cs:

```
using System;

namespace Functions
{
    public class Factorial
    {
        public static ulong CalcRecursively(int number)
        {
            if (number > 1)
                return (ulong)number * CalcRecursively(number - 1);
            if (number <= 1)
                return 1;

            return 0;
        }

        public static ulong Calc(int number)
        {
            ulong rValue=1;

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                rValue = rValue * (ulong)(number - i);                
            }

            return rValue;

        }


    }
}
```

MainProgram.cs:

```
using System;

using Functions;
class FunctionClient
{


    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n", Functions.Factorial.CalcRecursively(TESTED_VALUE));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n", Functions.Factorial.Calc(TESTED_VALUE));

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    const int TESTED_VALUE = 60;

}
```

Console:

> 9727775195120271360
>   9727775195120271360

It's ok with low figures, but otherwise(f.ex. with 60) it outputs the incorrect values, according to [the most reliable source on the internet](http://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Silnia). Could you point out my mistake? It's unbeliveable for me that the two totally different methods works wrong in  exactly the same manner.

Comment: I am not very experienced with C# but I had a hunch. The range of 

ulong is 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

while 60! = 8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000

I think you may see the problem here.

Comment: At the very least, give an example of an error case, with expected and actual values.

Comment: @HenkHolterman He did. (The expected is in the link.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running into the limits of C#'s ulong data type. It is a 64-bit data structure which limits it to a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you do want to explore larger numbers, .NET 4 introduced the [BigInteger structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) you may be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Numerics;

public static BigInteger Calc(int number)
{
    BigInteger rValue = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        rValue = rValue * (ulong)(number - i);
    }
    return rValue;
}
```

And add a reference to System.Numerics